# Can create a play 2.2.0 project -- Error adding module to project: Cannot create module

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.2

I have play 2.2.0 and IntellyJ Idea 12 and Play Framework plugin for it. I can create a play project due to the error `Error adding module to project: Cannot create module`

Why is that?