# Can't create new GAE (Python) Project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: python, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 13.1.4 I try to create a new Google App Engine Python project and I get the error message:

[image: Error adding module to project: provider 'facet:django not found]

> Error adding module to project: provider 'facet:django not found ([similar here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20210729/76066))

I've gone ahead and installed django into python27 folder, and I can create a default django project.

I'm running windows 8.1 and, if you couldn't already tell, new to this!

Comment: I'm trying to understand... you phrased it a bit confusingly.  You have django in the python27 folder, you can create a default project, and when you try to create a NEW project you get this error?

Comment: @julldar, I've no idea why it even mentioned django.. that's just the first step to dry and diagnose the issue! is django a red-herring?

Comment: I honestly don't know.  maybe some internal link doesn't work.  I personally use a Kepler Eclipse version with the cloud SDK and everything works fine.  With what you described I think everything should be swell as well

Answer (score 1):

Do you have free/community version of IntelliJ IDEA? or paid/ultimate?. I had a similar problem when I first created my app engine application on IntelliJ IDEA (but in this case I used java). I solved it downloading Ultimate.

Comment: I have Ultimate! I sort of solved the problem by forking out for PyCharm, but even then I has some issues..!